# how to install avchat 3 and red5 for php server?

Tags: php, chat, red5, videochat

I am trying to install avchat 3 on server but it is not working.
I have uploaded trial version of Avchat 3 and updated avchat.properties file with my ipaddress

```
application.adminsAllowedFromTheseIps=my ip address
```

Also ,

```
application.allowLocalhostConnections=true;
```

Someone has install then let me know how to install it?

Comment: Did you read this https://nusofthq.com/blog/why-would-avchat-3-fail-to-connect-to-the-media-server/

Comment: Yes. I have already read this link. i am not getting this error. Check my link yatin.site50.net. I don't have any idea about media server installation. i have just uploaded the file and changed the above configuration.

Comment: It seem that you're using some sort of portal site provider, this will not work. You need shell access to install red5, or have the provider do it for you.

Comment: Yes. I am using a free server. Will do and let you know.